# How to restrict the access to the web site using Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, devops, nestjs, vpn

I have React + Node.js app hosted in GCP.
What I want to do is not to allow anyone to go to our staging app.
I want to register IP addresses of our company's employees on GCP and allow only them to access the staging app.
Others can't access our staging app.
Is this possible?

Comment: If you're using App Engine, see [Controlling Access with Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/creating-firewalls)

Comment: The Google Cloud Firewall supports IP address restrictions. However, you should use authentication/authorization (login/password etc.) and not IP addresses. If your workers are at home, their IP addresses will change often. My home IP address changes every day.

Comment: On which service is hosted your app?

Comment: @JohnHanley, could you tell me more about authentication/authorization?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication